# How to force Espresso to kill my app after each UI test?

Tags: android-espresso

Espresso (also Kakao and Kaspresso) by default doesn't kill an application after each test. This is a very odd decision, cause we can have an Application class or some DI on the app level, so we have to clear manually all that stuff after each test is complete.
Can we somehow force espresso to kill the app?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AndroidX Test Orchestrator, you can pass in a Test Instrumentation Runner Argument. [More info here.](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/runner#enable-gradle)

Passing it in via gradle:

```
android {
 defaultConfig {
 ...
 testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

 // The following argument makes the Android Test Orchestrator run its
 // "pm clear" command after each test invocation. This command ensures
 // that the app's state is completely cleared between tests.
 testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
 }

 testOptions {
 execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
 }
}
```

Or via command line:

```
-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.clearPackageData=true
```